# How to pass json dictionary from javascript .get to django template?

Tags: javascript, json, django

In the head of my django template I currently have:

```
<script>
   $.get('get_students/', function (dict) {
        alert(dict)
   })
</script>
```

This alerts me of a json dictionary corresponding to dict, which comes from the following django view:

```
def get_students(request):
    students = Student.objects.all()

    students_json = serializers.serialize('json', students)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(students_json), content_type='application/json')
```

Is it possible to "escape" dict from the script tag into the normal Django template so that I can iterate over it with something like:

```
{% for d in dict%}
    <p>d.username</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If there is a more sensible way of doing this then please recommend it to me, I am still learning. Please note that I am working inside a component from which I have to call the view, which is why I am using js get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was to use JQuery. Inside the script tag I iterate over the dictionary values and append them to an innerHTML using a js string. So the .get above has to become something like:

```html
$.get('get_students/', function (data) {
            var write_to_div = document.getElementById("studentDiv");
            for (var d in data) {
                value = data[d]
                write_to_div.innerHTML += "<p>" + value['first_name'] + "</p>"

            }
        })
```

This will append a paragraphs containing all the first names of all the Users to the div with id "studentDiv", so in the HTML template I have

```html
<div id="studentDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't answer the question directly could this not be done by passing the data into the view with the [get_context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) method instead then looping over it?

So your view would look this this:

```
class ExampleDetailView(DetailView):
model = Student

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['contextDictionary'] = get_students()
    return context
```

then in the template have something like:

```
{% for d in contextDictionary %}
    <p>d.username</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My urls contains "url(r'^get_students/', get_students)," how would I reference this view? I don't mind how we do it as long as I can access it how you say without specifying a new template. Can you elaborate how to do this, I am not very familiar... I have a Student model, not a Publisher model, I also don't know how to call that view from my HTML template with a get...

Comment: In the code I posted you wouldn't call the code from a get request. You would pass it into the template directly through the view. Can you add your view and model to the template?

Comment: I don't think so. I am using a wagtail block component on my homepage, so the homepage is set and I cannot change the view it calls in urls, which is url(r'', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')) (unless one url can call two views?). So I think I have to call the other view from the template itself.